# How to get outer loop index inside anonymous function call?

Tags: javascript, anonymous-function

I have the following javascript code :

```
var Person = [['John', 0, 0, 0],['Chris', 1, 0, 0]];
for (i = 0; i < Person.length; i++ )
{
    someObj.myMethod(Person[i][0], function (object) {
        console.log(i); //this prints 2, I want 0 and 1 as per the loop

        //here I want to access other members of Person[i] array, like Person[i][1], Person[i][2] and Person[i][3]
        //but these console.log() print 'undefined' because i = 2 !!
        console.log(Person[i][1]);
        console.log(Person[i][2]);
        console.log(Person[i][3]);
    });
}
```

Inside the anonymous function called inside my myMethod(), value of i is '2'. Please suggest how to get  i = 0 in first cycle of for loop and then 1 in the second loop.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: you may check the underscore each function,

Comment: for(,,,,) will finished and the someObj.myMethod(Person[i][0], function (object) { this function is a callback so the i has already been set to 2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a closure, this a solution:

```
var Person = [['John', 0, 0, 0],['Chris', 1, 0, 0]];
for (x = 0; x < Person.length; x++ )
{
    (function(i){   //We add a closure
        someObj.myMethod(Person[i][0], function (object) {
          console.log(i);
          console.log(Person[i][1]);
          console.log(Person[i][2]);
          console.log(Person[i][3]);
      });
    })(x);      //Call the closure function with the value of the counter
}
```

I changed the original counter to `x` to make it more understandable (so you dont confuse that variable with the original `i`), but if it keeps named also `i`, it will work, too.

This way, each loop cycle has it's own variable `x` (*not shared*), so it doesn't get overwritten by the for loop, which was causing the problem (`i` was shared) :)

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

You have a leaky [closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work/111200#111200). Try this:

```
var Person = [['John', 0, 0, 0],['Chris', 1, 0, 0]];
for (i = 0; i < Person.length; i++ )
{
    doIt(i);
}

function doIt(i) {
    someObj.myMethod(Person[i][0], function (object) {
        console.log(i); //this prints 2, I want 0 and 1 as per the loop

        //here I want to access other members of Person[i] array, like Person[i][1], Person[i][2] and Person[i][3]
        //but these console.log() print 'undefined' because i = 2 !!
        console.log(Person[i][1]);
        console.log(Person[i][2]);
        console.log(Person[i][3]);
    });
}
```

Basically, your original inner anonymous function is being passed elsewhere to be executed later, by which stage the `i` variable has already been incremented to `2` in the for loop (they're effectively referencing the one copy of `i`).  Javascript is function scoped, so introducing a new function with it's own parameter to trap the specific value of `i`, you can decouple your anonymous function from the shared counter in the for loop.

Note that you can also make the function (`doIt` in my example) an immediately executing anonymous function like [Edgar has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21011002/), which means that no one else can call the logically private closure function (though it arguably makes it a little harder to read to someone not used to javascript closures).

Comment: I'm going to upvote this because you're at 9999. (Well, and it's right.)

Answer (score 2):

It depends *entirely* on *when* the callbacks are executed. If they are executed *immediately*, as the loop is running, then the values will be as you expect. The following outputs `0` and `1`:

```
var someObj = {
    myMethod: function(person, callback) {
        callback();
    }
}

var Person = [['John', 0, 0, 0],['Chris', 1, 0, 0]];
for (i = 0; i < Person.length; i++ )
{
    someObj.myMethod(Person[i][0], function (object) {
        console.log(i); 
    });
}
```

However, if the callbacks are *stored* and executed later, then (and this is the key thing to understand) each callback stored has closed over the *same* variable `i` and that variable's value is `2` after the loop has completed.

In other words, **the closure is over the variable itself, not its value at the time the closure is created**. As others have stated, this problem is easily solved using a wrapper function that receives `i` as an argument. This creates a *new* variable for each callback to close over.

Here's a contrived example:

```
var someObj = {

    callbacks: [],

    myMethod: function(person, callback) {
        someObj.callbacks.push(callback);
    }
}

var Person = [['John', 0, 0, 0],['Chris', 1, 0, 0]];
for (i = 0; i < Person.length; i++ )
{
    (function(i) {
        someObj.myMethod(Person[i][0], function (object) {
            console.log(i); 
        });
    })(i);
}

someObj.callbacks[0]();
someObj.callbacks[1]();
```

Another option in your case is to pass the elements of `Person` to your callback, instead of their index in the array.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to deal with closure issue that you have is to create local variable and pass it to your function.

```
var Person = [['John', 0, 0, 0],['Chris', 1, 0, 0]];

for (var i = 0; i < Person.length; i++ ) {
    var x = i;

    someObj.myMethod(Person[x][0], function (object) {
        console.log(Person[x][1]);
        console.log(Person[x][2]);
        console.log(Person[x][3]);
    });
}
```